# fyne.io を使用したソースコードのエラー: Attempt to access current Fyne app when none is started

Tags: go

以下のコードを実行したところ、エラーが発生しました。
ソースコードとエラーメッセージを記載するので、エラーの原因を教えてください。

ソースコード ↓

```
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "strings"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
)

func main() {
    fullText := "This\nis\nsample\ntext\n"
    fullTextLines := strings.Split(fullText, "\n")
    nLine := len(fullTextLines)

    texts := make([]fyne.CanvasObject, nLine)
    for _, line := range fullTextLines {
        text := canvas.NewText(line, color.Black)
        text.Alignment = fyne.TextAlignCenter
        texts = append(texts, text)
    }

    app := app.New()
    w := app.NewWindow("Title")

    content := container.New(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), texts...)

    w.SetContent(content)
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(300, 300))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

エラーメッセージ ↓（一部 *** にしてあります）

```
2021/02/14 09:11:48 Fyne error:  Attempt to access current Fyne app when none is started
2021/02/14 09:11:48   At: C:/Users/***/go/pkg/mod/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.0.0/app.go:79
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x60 pc=0xf098b6]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas.NewText(0x13d3a5c, 0x4, 0x142b840, 0x10629e0, 0x0)
        C:/Users/***/go/pkg/mod/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.0.0/canvas/text.go:46 +0x36
main.main()
        C:/Users/***/go/src/***/main.go:21 +0x165
exit status 2
```

Comment: `Attempt to access current Fyne app when none is started` と表示されていますので、`app := app.New()` を `for _, line := range fullTextLines { ... }` の前に置く必要があります。また、`texts := make([]fyne.CanvasObject, nLine)` の部分ですが、これでは append した時に `texts[nLine]` 以降に追加されてしまいますので `texts := make([]fyne.CanvasObject, 0, nLine)` とする必要があります(`cap` で指定)。

Comment: ご指摘の通り修正したところ、無事に動きました。ありがとうございました。